# Socket recv() made my string into a char "C:\User" 'C'

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, mfc

Why does string **a** return 'C' instead of "C:\Users\Desktop\Project phoneedge\ForMark\Top"?

When I tested it in a empty c++ project, and before I moved some of my code from ThreadFunction to StartButton it worked(The UI is suppose to update constantly but the socket recv() is cockblocking it causing it only update once so I moved the UI code to startbutton)

This is the server code, after start button is pressed, initiate the socket and there is a thread created to run the listen() accept() and recv(). The close button closes the socket and the thread.

Server Code(MFC project)

```
void CUIServerDlg::StartButton()
{
    WSADATA Winsockdata;
    int iTCPClientAdd = sizeof(TCPClientAdd);
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &Winsockdata);

    TCPServerAdd.sin_family = AF_INET;
    TCPServerAdd.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    TCPServerAdd.sin_port = htons(8000);

    TCPServersocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    bind(TCPServersocket, (SOCKADDR*)&TCPServerAdd, sizeof(TCPServerAdd));

    bRunning = true;
    hthread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunction, this, 0, &ThreadID);
    WaitForSingleObject(hthread, INFINITE);

    funRunning = true;
    while (funRunning == true) {
        vector<string> caseOne;
    

        /*string a;
        char RecvBuffer[512];//this is the declaration in member class
        int iRecvBuffer = strlen(RecvBuffer) + 1;*/

        **a = RecvBuffer;**//a is a String, RecvBuffer is a path name like c:\user..
        //Find files,This part of code is left out because it should not effect the question
        //put the files found in a vector, then display it on a listbox
        for (string fileVec : caseOne) {

            CString fileunderPath;
            string filevector1 = fileVec;
            fileunderPath = filevector1.c_str();//conversion for AddString
            list1.AddString(fileunderPath);
        }
        
        Sleep(1000);//The code updates every 1 second , when file names are modified is displays immediately.
    }    
}
```

I am suppose to change Sleep(1000) into WaitForSingleObject() to replace WM_Timer for the assignment but I don't know how since you need a handle, **do I create another thread?**

```
void CUIServerDlg::CloseButton()
{
    bRunning = false;
    funRunning = false;

    WaitForSingleObject(hthread, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(hthread);
    closesocket(TCPServersocket);
}
```

So I have never learned anything about socket and thread prior to this project, the idea of the code below is to use a thread to run a while loop to constantly check for new cilents to send things in, do make sure to correct me if the thought process is wrong.

```
DWORD WINAPI CUIServerDlg::ThreadFunction(LPVOID lpParam) {

    CUIServerDlg* This = (CUIServerDlg*)lpParam;
    while (This->bRunning == true) {

        int iListen = listen(This->TCPServersocket, 10);
        if (iListen == INVALID_SOCKET)
            OutputDebugString(_T("FAIL LISTEN\n"));

        This->sAccecpSocket = accept(This->TCPServersocket, (SOCKADDR*)&This->iTCPClientAdd, &This->iTCPClientAdd);
        recv(This->sAccecpSocket, This->RecvBuffer, This->iRecvBuffer, 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Client Code (Empty c++ project)

```
int main(){
    string a = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Project phoneedge\\ForMark\\Top";
    const char* SenderBuffer = a.c_str();
    int iSenderBuffer = strlen(SenderBuffer) + 1;

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &WinSockData);
    TCPClientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    TCPServerAdd.sin_family = AF_INET;
    TCPServerAdd.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    TCPServerAdd.sin_port = htons(8000);

    connect(TCPClientSocket,(SOCKADDR*)&TCPServerAdd,sizeof(TCPServerAdd));

    send(TCPClientSocket, SenderBuffer, iSenderBuffer, 0);
    closesocket(TCPClientSocket);

    WSACleanup();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `recv(This->sAccecpSocket, This->RecvBuffer, This->iRecvBuffer, 0);` -- Your code is fundamentally wrong when it comes to receiving data over a socket.  You should be using the return value of `recv` to know how many bytes were received, and then using that return value to determine how to form the string.  Do **not** use functions such as `strlen` or `strcpy`, or the constructor of `CString` that you are using, as they stop on the first null byte.

Comment: If you were to inspect the return value of `recv`, I bet that it isn't `1`, but some much larger value.  If so, that indicates exactly what the problem is, and where my comment above is relevant -- the data returned from `recv` has an embedded null, and you are not storing all of the data that was returned to you properly.  Also, you are to keep calling `recv` in a loop until all data has been received or an error occurs.

Comment: Is this piece of your code verbatim, or just an example? `char RecvBuffer[512]; int iRecvBuffer = strlen(RecvBuffer) + 1;` - if so, what are you trying to do here, get the size of the buffer?

Comment: There is too much code for me to want to test it. But finding only one character on Windows could be a hint that a wide character string were processed somewhere as if it was a narrow character one. In UTF16, all ascii character keep their value in the first byte... which is followed with a 0 byte! Just a wild guess but I would not be surprized with that...

Comment: @OP -- *Why does string a return 'C'...* -- Your code does not demonstrate that `a` contains only `'C'`.  You don't print out the buffer that `a` points to at all in your code.  What you **do** have is assigning all of this to a `CString`, and depending on the build type (MBCS or Unicode), a `CString` will hold either narrow or wide strings.  If the build type is Unicode, then `CString` will hold wide strings, and probably explains why you only see `'C`'.  That's why it is important to verify what `recv()` returns, so that you can identify that the code that processes the buffer is faulty.

Comment: On a side note: `hthread = CreateThread(...); WaitForSingleObject(hthread, INFINITE);` is a complete waste of a worker thread. You may as well just call `ThreadFunction()` directly instead, the end effect will be exactly the same - the calling thread will be blocked until `ThreadFunction()` exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TCP protocol passes the data by byte stream.

It means the client passes the data byte by byte rather than pass all the data at one time.

When you receive the data from the client. The passing procedure maybe not be finished.

So you need to check whether the data is finished passing after receiving some data by one `recv` call and then save the sub-data until receiving all the data.

Comment: The string was apparently passed but the strlen is not working properly Like Paul said, when I do iRecvBuffer+1  it passes back C://, so instead I fixed it by using sizeof(), tho i'm still not entirely sure how that works.